# In vs = Subquery Operators

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

On row three, When I changed `c.id =` to `c.id IN`, MYSQL indicated error. I wonder why is that as they are both operators that doing comparing/checking if exists in?

```
Select distinct c.Name As Name
from Candidate c
where c.id = (Select CandidateId 
              from Vote
              Group by CandidateId  
              order by count(CandidateId) desc
              limit 1)
```

Comment: When asking for help with an error, be sure to include the full text of the error message and error code.

Answer (score 0):

Either change that `=` to a `IN` operator (OR) use a `JOIN` statement

```
Select distinct c.Name As Name
from Candidate c
where c.id in (Select CandidateId 
              from Vote
              Group by CandidateId  
              order by count(CandidateId) desc
              limit 1)
```

Comment: Hi sorry I think my question phrasing was a bit confusing. The '=' was the correct answer. And 'in' led to error. I wonder why was that?